# Form field value not updating after changing value in UpdateView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have an app that has employee profiles and I can add safety courses for each profile. In the app I have a form that uses ModelChoiceField to get select values from the database. In the CreateView it works just fine. I can enter the dates and select the course for the profile and add it to the database. But the problem I'm having is when I update the safety course for the profile. When I update the form it updates the "conducted_date" and the "expiration_date", but the select form doesn't update. When I enter the update form the form doesn't even select the value that it currently has, for example:

If I have a profile for "John Doe" and I added "course1" to his profile, that works fine, but when I go to edit the profile, "course1" isn't selected but rather "course2" is selected. Then when I chose another course like "course3" and press submit, the "conducted_date" and "expiration_date" gets updated but not the course. So what exactly am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

forms.py

```
class SafetyCourseTakenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    course = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SafetyCourse.objects.all(), empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = SafetyCoursesTaken
        fields = [
            'conducted_date',
            'expiration_date',
        ]
```

views.py

```
class AddSafetyCourseTakenView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    form_class = SafetyCourseTakenForm
    template_name = 'ppm/forms/add-course-taken.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ppm:manage-courses-taken')
    success_message = 'Safety course has been added to profile'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        course_taken = form.save(commit=False)
        course_taken.user = self.request.user
        course_taken.profile_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        course_taken.course_id = form.data['course']
        return super(AddSafetyCourseTakenView, self).form_valid(form)

    # override success_url to redirect to url with primary key
    def get_success_url(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        return reverse('ppm:manage-courses-taken', kwargs={'pk': pk})


class UpdateSafetyCourseTakenView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    model = SafetyCoursesTaken
    form_class = SafetyCourseTakenForm
    template_name = 'ppm/forms/update-course-taken.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ppm:manage-courses-taken')
    success_message = 'Safety course has been updated for profile'

    def get_success_url(self):
        profile = SafetyCoursesTaken.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return reverse('ppm:manage-courses-taken', kwargs={'pk': profile.profile_id})
```

I've also tried setting **init** in my forms.py but that didn't work either.

```
SafetyCourseTakenForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SafetyCourseTakenForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['course'].queryset = SafetyCourse.objects.all()
```

So to reiterate. Why is my UpdateView only updating the 'conducted_date' and 'expiration_date' fields but NOT the 'course' field and why doesn't the select field have the proper form value on the edit form?

Note: If you need more information then provided, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified that `course` is a field associated with the model; the only fields that will be saved are `conducted_date` and `expiration_date`. Make sure that `course` is also in the Meta.fields list.

Comment: Wow that was simple but I was close, I tried a variation of that. I tried to use "course_id" in the Meta.fields list, but that didn't work and I didn't think to just try "course". Much appreciated.

Since that works then that also makes "course_taken.course_id = form.data['course']" redundant in my AddSafetyCourseTakenView.